# Functional dependency and many-to-many relationships

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I have these fields:

```
A   book_id
B   book_title
C   book_isbn
D   book_year
G   reader_id
H   reader_name
I   reader_birthday
L   reader_phone
M   reader_email
N   reader_registration_date
O   loan_id
P   loan_date_issued
S   loan_date_for_return
T   loan_date_returned
U   author_id
V   author_name
W   category_id
X   category_name
```

and these dependencies:

```
A->BCD
G->HILMN
O->AGPST
U->AV
W->AX
```

After all calculations I get this:

```
R1 = ABCD       k1 = {A}    Books
R2 = GHILMN     k2 = {G}    Readers
R3 = AGOPST     k3 = {O}    Loans
R4 = AUV        k4 = {U}    Authors
R5 = AWX        k5 = {W}    Category
R6 = OUW        k6 = {OUW}  {Don’t know}
```

But this is not good because table Book has a many to many relationship with table Category, and so do the Book and Author tables.
I'm stuck. I think I'm doing something wrong from the start and after that all goes wrong. Maybe you have some example for this.

Comment: I think the functional dependency (FD) W->AX is bad; it says that a category ID controls a book ID and a category name. That makes no sense. W->X is a perfectly sane functional dependency. A->W makes sense; a book is in a particular category identified by the category ID. Similarly, the U->AV FD is bad; U->V is a perfectly sane functional dependency, but  A->U is more nearly plausible. Note that a single book can have multiple authors, so you wouldn't combine the A->U dependency with the A->BCD. A single book might have multiple categories too; you wouldn't combine A->W with A->BCD either.

Comment: R6 (OUW) makes no sense: why would a loan ID, author ID and category ID identify anything useful?  I observe that the book ID (A) is an ambiguous term.  It isn't clear whether it describes a particular copy of a particular book, or all the copies of a book ever created by the publisher.  A library may have several copies of a particular edition of a particular book (and these days, the copy of the book will have a unique number assigned by the library so that it can be tracked), but it isn't clear that the schema has this in mind (the Book table would have lots of repetition in it).

Comment: So, I think you need to review the dependencies.  Are they what you created, or were they imposed on you by a teacher?  If they were imposed on you, you should discuss with your teacher why the W->AX and U-AV dependencies are an accurate representation of reality as modelled by the relational schema in the question.  You may need to think about what a book really is — is the Book ID really an ISBN (where every copy of an edition shares the same ISBN), or is it a 'library accession number' where every book has a distinct number so that it can be tracked individually.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Presumably by "combine" FDs that hold you mean something about not having a single table with both FDs holding, but that is really about an alternate design rather than a decomposition of this one, since you are really talking about FDs holding in different tables with different predicates, and those predicates/tables don't arise from decomposing this design.)

Comment: @philipxy: more or less.  If you had R10 = ABCDU, you could not represent a book with multiple authors cleanly; it makes much more sense to keep R1 = ABCD and introduce another relation R11 = AU.  The primary key of R11 is AU; the primary key of R1 is just A.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But if you decompose based on one predicate, generating certain component predicates, then decide that you don't *want* those predicates, then it does not make any sense to pay any attention to the decomposition so far because the new predicates establish new FDs for both themselves and their join! And decomposing an inappropriate design is not a good source of predicates or FDs for an appropriate design! You're essentially randomly producing schemas to inspire you. If you wrote things out clearly this would be evident. Meanwhile how can the OP understand? (Hence my answer.)

Comment: Well, I disagree with the FD set that is given, so … I'm off to bed.

Comment: 1. What NF are you normalizing to? 2. What algorithm are you using? (Give a reference.) 3. The statement of your problem, "table Book has a many to many relationship with table Category, and so do the Book and Author tables", is unintelligible, please rephrase. Use more words. What relationships? (FKs? Tables? Projections?) 4. Please explain why "this is not good".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's treat "category" as "cover" of a "book"-as-object or "copy" of a "book"-as-text, where a "book" is associated with some O values unique to it. Then W -> A makes more intuitive sense. (Other FDs seem unintuitive too.)

**Universal relations**

Every table (base or query result) has a predicate (statement template) that a row makes either into a true statement (and goes in the table) or a false statement (and stays out). We say the table represents the business relationship/association characterized by the predicate. A guess at a predicate here is:

```
book A titled B with isbn C published in year D
    was borrowed by a reader G named H born on date I
        with phone# L and email address M registered on date N
    in loan O issued on date P due on date S
    and either it was returned on date T or it is not yet returned and T=NULL
    and it was written by author U named V
    and the library has A in cover/copy W named X
```

You seem to be using the "universal relation" decomposition design/normalization technique. But this is only applicable if your one table satisfies the "universal relation assumption". Which is that all your situations can be described via the one predicate and its one table.

Eg: Suppose you can have books that have not been loaned or users that haven't borrowed. Then *the example predicate/table above could not record them*. So a decomposition wouldn't be able to record them. So you would instead start with a different predicate/table. (Typically multiple ones.)

Eg: If the last line was `and A was borrowed in cover/copy W named X` then the table could hold a different value in a given situation than before. But depending on the borrowing policy the table could satisfy the same set of FDs.

What *is* the predicate for this table? If it's not what you guessed, your expectations might not be met.

**Your decomposition**

Let's ignore the properties of entities.

```
-- O is G borrowing A by U with W

A   book_id
G   reader_id
O   loan_id
U   author_id
W   cover/copy_id

O->AG
U->A
W->A
```

The only CK is OUW. Here is an obvious decomposition to BCNF. It agrees with your version.

```
-- O is G borrowing A by someone with some cover/copy
-- O is G borrowing A
Loan(O,G,A)

-- some loan is somebody borrowing A by U with some cover/copy
-- the book of U is A
The_book_of_author(U,A)

-- some loan is somebody borrowing A by someone with W
-- the book of W is A
The_book_of_cover/copy(W,A)

-- O is somebody borrowing some book by U with W
-- O is the borrowing of the book of U and W
Author_and_cover/copy(O,U,W)
```

The original relation is the join of the components:

```
--     O is G borrowing A
    and the book of U is A
    and the book of W is A
    and O is the borrowing of the book of U and W
-- O is G borrowing A by U with W
Loan JOIN The_book_of_author JOIN The_book_of_cover/copy JOIN Author_and_cover/copy
```

> this is not good because table Book has a many to many relationship with table Category, and so do the Book and Author tables

Unfortunately this is unintelligible. So I can't address what you mean to say is wrong.

**Database design**

If you generated this design yourself, you should be using some reference information modeling method. This will guide you to determine reasonable predicates/tables to record all the situations that can arise according to your business rules.

Predicates applied to what situations can arise determine what states can arise. Those valid states are described by constraints--FDs (functional dependencies), JDs (join dependencies), CKs (candidate keys), FKs (foreign keys) (aka "relationships" in a different sense than above), etc.

Part of a method is normalizing provisional tables to others. This uses FDs & JDs to decompose to an appropriate NF (normal form) via an appropriate algorithm. A good method always normalizes to 5NF. (Even if you denormalize it later for implementation reasons.)